# LINQtoSQL: Summing an IN clause with multiple items

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to figure out how to translate the following SQL statement into LINQ to SQL:

```
, SUM(CASE WHEN p.prioid IN ('1 - Routine', '6 - Planned Outage', '7-Routine Weekly PM', '8-Routine Non-Weekly PM') THEN 1 ELSE     0 END) as Planning
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Planning = groupItem.Sum(groupItem.Key.Prioid=="1 - Routine" || groupItem.Key.Prioid=="6 - Planned Outage"||
        groupItem.Key.Prioid=="7-Routine Weekly PM" || "8-Routine Non-Weekly PM") ? 1 : 0


Planning = groupItem.Sum(x=> SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "1 - Routine") || SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "6 - Planned Outage")
        || SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "7-Routine Weekly PM") || SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "8-Routine Non-Weekly PM")) ? 1 : 0
```

and a couple of other things as well but none of them work because you cannot convert a bool into an int or you "Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func"

I understand why the way I tried to do it does not work.

So how DO you do it?  I know there is a way, I just don't know enough about LINQ to SQL to figure it out.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it odd that the above wouldn't work because I though I had done this in the past.  After looking at my past work and comparing it with this I seen that I made a very stupid mistake and put my ending parenthesis in the wrong place.  It should have looked like this:

```
Planning = groupItem.Sum(x=> SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "1 - Routine") || SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "6 - Planned Outage")
        || SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "7-Routine Weekly PM") || SqlMethods.Like(x.Prioid, "8-Routine Non-Weekly PM" ) ? 1 : 0)
```